# Trigger Azure Pipeline With an empty payload from Azure EventGrid

Tags: azure-api-management, azure-eventgrid, azure-webhooks

I have an `API Management service` that I would like to call an Azure pipeline when changes occur in the APIM.

The Event in APIM allows the creation of a webhook through `EventGrid`. however, I am looking at how to call the endpoint with the empty JSON payload.

According to [Runs - Run Pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/pipelines/runs/run-pipeline?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0) we can run the pipeline through RestApi. I am configuring this endpoint with the correct headers.

From `Postman` I can call the Run Pipeline endpoint with the below;

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://dev.azure.com/organization/project/_apis/pipelines/pipelineId/runs' \
--header 'Accept: api-version=7.0' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--header 'Authorization: Basic PAT'
--data '{}'
```

In the APIM => Create Event Subscription => Delivery Properties [Custom delivery properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/delivery-properties)
of EventGrid, I couldn't find a way to add an empty payload. This empty payload is required while sending a request from the Postman.

So how to add an empty payload to the request as above in the `EventGrid Webhook?`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using [WebHook Event Delivery](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/webhook-event-delivery), Event Grid performs a handshake as documented for it to work and always includes a payload.

You should proxy the request using a different service. Here are some options

**1. Use APIM**
This is to use the same APIM instance to get the Event Grid event and forward it to the DevOps API.

[Here](https://github.com/Azure/api-management-policy-snippets/blob/master/examples/Forward%20Azure%20Event%20Grid%20Event.xml) is a custom policy example to get started.

**2. Use Azure Functions**
The binding for Azure Functions handles this for you, and since this is code-based, you can perform any other action or processing required before calling the DevOps API.

Check the [official docs for how Azure Functions can be used as an event handler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/handler-functions).

Comment: Yes, Ws looking at option 2.